# How to scroll on Textbox(multiline) in C# WPF, by mouse-dragging, not by mouse-wheel?

Tags: wpf

My TextBox is read-only. and contents is increased more...

Vertical scroll bar of textbox is showed(auto), then user can scroll it by mouse-wheel. it's ok now.
But if i'm going to scroll by mouse-drag on scroll-bar's seek, it's impossible and instead of it, form is moved.
(i used metro-form using mahapp.dll)

How i can scroll the textbox contents by mouse-dragging the seek of textbox scroll-bar?

Comment: The default behaviour of the WPF `TextBox` already enables the user to scroll it by clicking inside its bounds and dragging. Therefore, I don't understand your question... can you please clarify what it is? What does '*the seek of textbox scroll-bar*' mean?